# How to Add Red5 Background Startup on Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: command-line, server, apt, bash, red5

I followed the instructions in here to install `red5` manually through tarball because the apt-get does not work for Ubuntu 14.04:
[Ubuntu Trusty red5-server installation fails to start](https://askubuntu.com/questions/674859/ubuntu-trusty-red5-server-installation-fails-to-start)

Even with installing the dependencies manually the server will always fail. The red5 server now works but the terminal must be open and just hang there. I need a startup script to run the process in the background. The conversation here:
http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29197/discussion-between-umi-and-pl-rock

I followed but it doesn't work properly. Now the result is:

In `init.d/red5` I have two lines - `start on filesystem` & `exec /bin/bash /usr/share/red5.sh`.

`update rc.d red5 defaults` returns:

```
missing LSB information
```

`sudo service red5 stop` returns:

```
stop: Unknown instance
```

`sudo service red5 start` returns:

```
red5 stop/waiting
```

Comment: I am doing the installation of Red5 that I have been meaning to do for a long time.  Im checking it now to see how I pulled it off with other 3 servers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sorry by mistake i wrote there wrong syntax in chat .

**First method :**

create any file under `/etc/init.d`

```
sudo nano /etc/init.d/red5
```

add lines

```
 #!/bin/sh
cd /full-path/red5-server-1.0.6-RELEASE/ && ./red5.sh &
```

save this file and exit then make it executable

```
sudo chmod ugo+x /etc/init.d/red5
```

then run command

```
sudo update-rc.d red5 defaults
```

your problem is solved. you can start it using

```
sudo service red5 start
```

**Second method :**

you can use `/etc/rc.local`.
`/etc/rc.local` is where you can customize your own daemon to run in the background.  Daemon is what does the job in running whichever scripts you want system to run in the background.  This is where the system picks up to start daemons before releasing the system to you for your use.

open it using command

```
sudo nano /etc/rc.local
```

add  bellow command before `exit 0`

```
cd /full_path/red5-server-1.0.6-RELEASE/ && ./red5.sh &
```

and you can test if this is working correctly or not

```
sh /etc/rc.local
```

next time you start your system or reboot your red5 server will run in background.  it will work.

**Third method :**

create any `.conf` file under `/etc/init`

```
sudo nano /etc/init/red5.conf
```

add bellow lines

```
start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [016]
exec /full-path/red5-server-1.0.6-RELEASE/red5.sh
```

now you  start server

```
sudo service red5 start
```

if you want to create better upstart then read [Upstart Intro, Cookbook and Best Practises](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/)

Comment: Using the first method I still get "start: Unknown job: red5". In /etc/init.d/red5 i have "#!/bin/sh" and "cd /usr/share/red5/ && ./red5.sh &" In  Also will this method startup red5 server when the VPS restarts?

Comment: all three method i have tested on my ubuntu 14.04 is working . but , first one is not working then use second method it will solve your problem.  my upstart script is basic . if you want to add all function reload , restart , stop etc. then you have put more effort to write it . if you just want to run in background then use second method.

Comment: I got it to work using the 2nd method! just tested after reboot, my red5 server was up!!! I think this will help so many people.