# Red5-Server intall fails on Ubuntu 14.o4

Tags: dependencies, red5

Trying to install red5-server (as part of Kaltura installation process)  on Ubuntu 14.04, I got these messages:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:  libtomcat7-java :
Conflicts: libtomcat6-java but 6.0.39-1 is to be installed. The
following actions will resolve these dependencies:

    Keep the following packages at their current version: 1)     libtomcat7-java [Not Installed]                    

    Leave the following dependencies unresolved:          2)     libmina2-java recommends libtomcat7-java           


Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?] y
```

Manual install of missing packages is useless, as well as not accepting the proposed solution and following others.

I'm on AWS instance an dlooking at the source repo I find this line:

```
http://eu-west-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe red5-server all 1.0~svn4374-3 [111 kB]
```

So I'm getting release 1.0 while the current release is 1.6?

Answer (score 0):

this is bug [see here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/red5/+bug/1312814).
you can install it manually .you can follow step explained in my another answer
[how to install red5](https://askubuntu.com/a/674879/432559)